# Нужно ли мне знать Sass , для изучения Bootstrap?

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap, websocket

В  **http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/**  много всего как я понял связанного с Sass нужно ли знать эту технологию или можно обойтись без него ,при изучении Bootstrap 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не нужно, Bootstrap написан на Sass, но для его использования не обязательно знать Sass, вы можете просто скачать Bootstrap, уже скопилированный в CSS.